# How to attach children to the parent object in hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got some objects, one called "Parent", 3 called "Child" (Nr. 1 in the picture). How can I make, at runtime, the "Child" objects be actual children of the "Parent" object (Nr. 2 in the picture)?

[image]

Comment: transform.setParent(parentObject);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should works:

```
public GameObject Parent;
public List<GameObject> Childs;

public void SetParent(){
    foreach(var child in Childs){
        child.transform.SetParent(Parent, false);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The second parameter of `SetParent` tells Unity to keep the world's parameters of your object:

> worldPositionStays: If true, the parent-relative position, scale and rotation are modified such that the object keeps the same world space position, rotation and scale as before.

Comment: I feel the need to point that **false** in SetParent(...) is crucial ;).
If you care about the order of your child objects, use:
**child.transform.SetAsLastSibling();**

Answer (score 2):

One of many ways is:

create a class to hold an arbitrary number of Child objects.

```
public class Children: List<Child> {}
```

then, add a property to the Parent class of that type

```
public class Parent
{
    public Children Children { get; set; }

}
```

then just add the 3 Child objects to the Children Property

```
var p = new Parent();
p.Children = new Children();
p.Children.Add(new Child());
p.Children.Add(new Child());
p.Children.Add(new Child());
```

access the Child objects just like you would any other property

```
var child1 = p.Children[0];
var child2 = p.Children[1];
var child3 = p.Children[2];
```

or

```
foreach( var c in p.Children)
   //.... do something
```